# cannot resove symbol TransitionsReceiver

Tags: java, android-studio, activity-recognition

Trying to test next Google sample https://developer.android.com/codelabs/activity-recognition-transition#4 I was stuck on 5 step.

```
private TransitionsReceiver mTransitionsReceiver;
```

return me next error message "cannot resolve symbol TransitionReceiver".

On my build.gradle I have

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: you've already imported the library into your activity code, right?If yes, have you tried to implement an older version? (Try with 19.0.1). So: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'

Comment: I tested with ver. 19.0.1. Same result. Looking like my Android Studio never heared by TransitionReceiver.

Comment: but you've already imported the library into your activity code? the TransitionsReceiver object in: `private TransitionsReceiver mTransitionsReceiver` the IDE points it out to you red? or is it just red without underlining? because if red with underlining you would have to import the package into the imports of that activity